What is the probability that their median will be with $1$ and $2$?
I was practicing some tricky probability questions and I got a question on a private community math page:
Suppose $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are $3$ random variables from a uniform $[0,3]$ distribution. What is the probability that their median will be with $1$ and $2$?
However, I was confused of what does the question mean by median for three variables within $1$ and $2$. I was thinking in this way, now for one variable $X_1$ I think the probability for median within $1$ and $2$ is $\frac13$. For two variables it should be probability in the area $[1,2]\times[1,2]$ in 2D of $\frac13 \times \frac13$. For three variables it should be a cube of probability $\frac13 \times \frac13 \times \frac13$. But the answer is given as $\frac{13}{162}$. Do you have any clue or how do you perceive/approach this problem?
I couldn't ask/clarify my questions there as it was paid.

The problem is not clear.  Are the $X_i$ continuous or discrete?  Are they pairwise and jointly independent?  What does it mean for their median to be "with $1$ and $2$"?

I don't think it can mean "the median lies between $1$ and $2$" as you appear to suggest.  After all, the probability that one of them lies between $0$ and $1$, and another lies between $1$ and $2$ and the third lies between $2$ and $3$ is $\frac 6{27}$ which is already greater than the official solution (and, of course, there are other ways for the median to wind up in the middle third).

I think it is continuous. I am also curious how do you get $6/27$? In the hint in that page was also written that for the second variable the value might be less than 2 which has probability $2/3$ or greater than $1$ which also has probability $2/3$. Blah blah blah

There are $6$ possible orders, hence the factor of $6$.  Let's look just at $x_1<x_2<x_3$.  The probability that $X_1$ is in the first third is $\frac 13$, the probability that $X_2$ is in the second third is again $\frac 13$ and of course the same for $X_3$.  Thus the probability, conditioned on this order, is $\frac 1{27}$.  The factor of $6$ gets you all the possible orders.

But, really, the question is hopeless unless we are told what it means for the median to be "with $1$ and $2$".  That sounds like something Google Translate came up with.  We could try to reverse engineer the solution, $162=2\times 3^4$ which might be suggestive?  But nothing leaps to mind.

The question (title included) as written does not make sense .

@leonbloy I agree. Even I was puzzled so I thought trying my luck here. If I get some sense of the question.

My understanding of this question is $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are i.i.d R.V. with uniform distribution on $[0,3]$. Let $X_{(1)},X_{(2)},X_{(3)}$ be the order statistics. That is, $X_{(1)},X_{(2)},X_{(3)}$ is a permutaion of $X_1,X_2,X_3$ s.t. $X_{(1)}\leq X_{(2)}\leq X_{(3)}$. What we want to compute is $\mathbb{P}(1\leq X_{(2)}\leq 2)$.
In fact, we have an explicit formula for the density of order statistics. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic.
In this question, the pdf of $X_{(2)}$ is
$$p(x)=\frac{2}{3}x(1-\frac{x}{3})$$
Thus the probability is
$$\int_1^2p(x)dx=\frac{13}{27}$$

This one makes a lot of sense. In wiki I see the formula $\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}u^{k-1}(1-u)^{n-k}$. Shouldn't we have $n=3, k=2, u= x/3$ then we would have $2x(1-x/3)$. How do we get 2/3 as a coefficient?

You forget a term f(x) (the density of X_i), which in this question is equal to 1/3.

Yeah, I saw a documentation https://www.colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/order_stats.pdf
It is hard to understand just from the formula, how 1/3 is coming!

I think you find the wrong formula. The formula should be $\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}f(x)F(x)^{k-1}(1-F(x))^{n-k}$. Here $f(x)$ is the pdf of $X_i$ and $F(x)$ is the cdf of $X_i$.

+1 The R code pbeta(2/3,2,2) - pbeta(1/3,2,2) giving 0.4814815 confirms $\frac{13}{27}$

And we get 13/162 by dividing 13/27 by $3!=6$.
